# JSON String format

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm saving JSON string (using javascript's JSON.stringify) via Ajax call to a php script that write this string into a file i.e.

```
<?php

    $msg = $_GET['hecdata'];

    if (strlen($msg) > 0)
    {
        $file = fopen("hecdata.txt","w");
        fwrite($file,$msg);
        fclose($file);

        echo "True";        
    }
    else
    {
        echo "False";               
    }

?>
```

but the problem is the format of JSON become:

`[{\"customerName\":\"Customer 1\",\"contactNumber\":\"03001234567\",\"hallName\":\"4\",\"bookingDate\":\"09/30/2013\"}]`

which is not correct, I am new to php, is this how we should save a json string into a text file?

Comment: [Magic Quotes?](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)

Comment: What @deceze said. You have magic quotes enabled on your server, which is escaping all the quotes. This has nothing to do with JavaScript, JSON or any of the PHP code you've shown :p

Comment: It would, indeed, appear to be a magic-quotes issue, [which you should disable ASAP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php)

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
$msg = stripslashes($msg);
```

and then write it to file. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

JSON is correct, you have extra brace "}" on this string

Comment: Sorry about that edited the json, I just took some data from the whole string.